# Get all entries related to a specific Entity based on relationship in Swift Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a simple two entity Core Data database
Entity 1
 - Attribute 1
 - Attribute 2
Entity 2
 - Attribue 1

The relationship is defined so for every Entity 1, I can have many Entity 2's.

I have selected a single Entity 1 - via a UITableView
I would now like to retrieve all the Entity 2 records.  I am trying with NSPredicate but that seems like it is the wrong way.. Here's that code - which cannot invoke initialize for NSPredicate:

```
   lazy var entity2Predicate: NSPredicate = { return NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", #keyPath(Entity1.relationship), ascending: true)}()
```

What is the correct way to define the fetch for all the Entity2 records related to Entity1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Entity2`'s always relate to exactly one `Entity1`, I think the simplest way to achieve this involves defining a one-to-many relationship between `Entity1` and `Entity2` in your Core Data model.

1. Select `Entity1`. Under Relationships, click the + button to add a relationship. Name it something meaningful. Since you haven't told us the real names of your entities, I'll call the relationship `entityTwos` in this example.
2. Set the Type of relationship to "To Many".
3. If `Entity1` is not required to have any `Entity2`'s, set the relationship to Optional.
4. Set the Delete Rule to "Cascade" so that when `Entity1` is deleted, any related `Entity2`'s are also deleted.
5. Now, select `Entity2`. Add a Relationship, give it a name (say `entityOne`) and set its Inverse to the name of the relationship created in Step 1 (`entityTwos` in this example).
6. Uncheck the Optional option, and set the Type to "To One". Set the Delete Rule to "Nullify".

You'll also need to add properties for the relationships in your entity classes. In `Entity1`:

```
@NSManaged var entityTwos: NSSet
```

In `Entity2`:

```
@NSManaged var entityOne: Entity1
```

Having done that, you can easily access all the `Entity2`'s related to an `Entity1` without any querying, like this:

```
//here, entity1 is an instance of Entity1
entity1.entityTwos
```

What's really cool is you can also go the other way:

```
//here, entity2 is an instance of Entity2
entity2.entityOne
```

Comment: Thank you, so one additional question.  First yes, Entity2 will only ever match to one Entity1,  But I can have an Entity1 with no Entity2's so in that case I have it checked as Optional.  And if I grab the Entity1.entityTwos - I assume that returns a set that I can then assign to a tableview for scrolling thru all the values. (I know this statement is a bit of an oversimplification, but I've done this basic concept in loading a list of Entity1's.)

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. entityTwos is an NSSet which has an allObjects property for accessing the objects. I usually force cast this to an array because arrays are easier to work with: entity1.entityTwos.allObjects as! [Entity2].

Comment: Will be raising another question, as I now have a different crash, I think it is how I am trying to load NSSet (and deal with the empty Set)